# How is the main deity at an ISKCON temple chosen?

Tags: gods, temple, worship, iskcon

For example, at the ISKCON London temple, the principal dieties are Rādhā-Kṛṣṇa according to [their website](https://www.iskcon-london.org/visit/see-our-shrine).

> [image]
>
> **About the Deities**
>
> On the right-hand side of the shrine, you will see **Radha-Krishna** deities...They are **the principal deities at our Temple**.
>
> On the left-hand side of the shrine, you will see Lord Jagannath (another form of Krishna on the right-hand side of this part of the shrine), Lord Baladeva (Krishna's brother, on the left-hand side) and Lady Subhadra (Krishna's sister, in between Jagannath and Baladeva)...These unusual deities are based on the original deities in Jagannatha Puri located in Orissa, India.
>
> In the centre part of the shrine, you will see Sri Sri Gaura-Nitai - the incarnations of Krishna and Balarama - and who are the propagators of harinama sankirtan which is the process for spiritual perfection in this age.

While at [ISKCON Hawaii](https://www.iskconhawaii.com/daily-darshan), the main deity appears to be [Pañca-tattva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancha_Tattva_(Vaishnavism)):

[image]

So how does ISKCON decide which deities to install at any temple and which should be the principal deity?

Comment: They decide randomly. You will often see Radha krishn, shri Chaitanya and Nityanand prabhu or panchtatva or Jagannath baladev subhadra. But then they randomly place 1 deity as main or at center

Comment: If you know of an official/authentic reference, you can write an answer. @Vishalprabhulawande